# printing from within a method how it was called, or how it's caller was called for debug

Tags: debugging, printing

I am a Python newbie... excuse my newness.
I would like to have something like this:

def my_func (arg list in any acceptable form):

```
my_func_call = you_name_this_one()
print(my_func_call)
```

1 - I would like to be able to run from the console the produced line so that debug is made easy

I - It would be great to be able to deliver to you_name_this_one a depth argument that would allow me to get the same for the caller of my_func, or to the caller of the caller, and so on.